# Unable to open Minecraft Forge 1.7.10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-forge

I have downloaded Forge 1.7.10, but when I try to install it I get the message:

> You need to run the version 1.7.10 manual at least once.

I don't really get what I'm supposed to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a modded version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 4):

It means what it says. You must play Minecraft 1.7.10 before installing forge 1.7.10.
Once you play it, you can exit. Find and click on the forge installer and it should tell you the installation was successful. When you open up your launcher again, it should automatically be set to the new profile just created. You must run it before putting any mods into the mods folder. The mods folder can be found in

```
%AppData%\Roaming\.minecraft\mods
```

or if running Linux:

```
/home/username/.minecraft/mods
```

Also, if you already installed forge properly and it still won't start, make sure you don't have Java 8 installed. As of now, forge is incompatible with Java 8 and will not start if you use it in Java 8 runtime. You must use Java 7 until this bug is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is that you haven't played 1.7.10 before installing Forge.

to my knowledge, the Forge Installer does not download Minecraft resources as such if you want to install it for a particular version you first have to run Minecraft for that version to allow the launcher to download the Version Files

By Default, the first Profile titled by your username used to log into Minecraft will get the current, non-snapshot version of Minecraft. for lower versions of Minecraft you with to install Forge for you can do 2 things.

1. Alter your profile by change the selection for "User Version"
2. Create a New Profile and change the selection for "User Version"

this functionality is known as the [Time Machine](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_launcher#Time_Machine)

> The Minecraft launcher has the ability to play old Alpha and Beta versions of the game. Currently, Alpha, Beta, and all Release versions are available to play. Four Pre-classic versions, four Classic versions, and an Infdev version are already added under the names "old-alpha version". However, Indev is still missing...
>
> To enable the old versions either click the "Edit Profile" button or, preferably, create a new one. Under the "Version Selection" section choose to allow use of Alpha and/or Beta versions by ticking the appropriate boxes. Next, select the desired version from the drop-down menu and save the profile.

after that you then play the profile. this will get the Launcher to download the Version file. let Minecraft reach the title screen and confirm the Minecraft Version you are playing then quit out. after that you can install Forge

Comment: I should also note that if you only just got Minecraft.exe and try to install Forge for even the current version it will still fail, all versions of Minecraft have to be played at least once for the launcher to get their version file

Answer (score 0):

You must first go into your launcher, then open 1.7.10 normally, then exit out right when you get to the title screen, then install forge, this is how it works on every version of Minecraft.

Mac Minecraft folder: ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft
Windows Minecraft folder: %appdata%/.minecraft

When in the Minecraft folder, find the folder "mods" and put your .jar mods inside. :D